# Is it okay to delete .git directory in AWS OpsWorks S3 deployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef, opsworks

I'm using AWS OpsWorks S3 deployment for quite some time. Suddenly the deployment fails. When I checked the instance, it turns out the disk is full. When I checked the release path inside the `/srv/www/app/release/release_paths` has a `.git` directory in it that turns out eats a lot of space.

I'm wondering why there is a `.git` directory in the release path when I use S3 deployment, not git deployment. Can I safely remove the .git directory on the deployment hook to free some space?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's not a good idea to outright delete them.

> I'm wondering why there is a .git directory in the release path when I
>   use S3 deployment, not git deployment.

The [Chef deploy](https://docs.chef.io/resource_deploy.html) resource doesn't have an option to deploy from a zip (as oppose to from version control). To get around that OpsWorks downloads the zip and [initializes a Git repository](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/release-chef-11.10/scm_helper/libraries/s3.rb#L29) in it, then runs deploy on that.

> When I checked the release path inside the
>   /srv/www/app/release/release_paths

Did you mean `releases/<some date>` or `shared/cached-copy`? I don't think `release` is a standard directory in the default Chef deploy directory layout.

> Can I safely remove the .git directory on the deployment hook to free
>   some space?

If you mean `releases/<some date>` then no. This is used for the [rollback](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingapps-deploying.html) command, allowing you to revert back to one of those previous versions.

If you really need the space the default number of versions to keep is 5, but you could reduce this by overriding the [[:opsworks][:deploy_keep_releases]](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/release-chef-11.10/deploy/attributes/deploy.rb#L23) attribute.

Comment: Sorry, i mean `releases/<some date>`, there is a `.git` directory inside it that consumes a lot of space.